# The LINQ expression could not be translated using .ToDictionary()

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm migrating from Entity Framework 4.6 to Entity Framework Core 6 and I get an error while trying to get list of rooms.

This is the code I use:

```
var rooms_ = context.Rooms
                    .Include(q => q.AreaType)
                    .Where(q => floorsIds.Contains(q.ParentId.Value))
                    .Where(r => r.AreaTypeId.HasValue && !r.IsDeleted)
                    .GroupBy(r => r.AreaTypeId.Value)
                    .ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.ToList());
```

This is the error I got:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(q => __floorsIds_0.Contains(q.ParentId.Value))
> .Where(r => r.AreaTypeId.HasValue && !(r.IsDeleted))
> .GroupBy(r => r.AreaTypeId.Value)'
>
> could not be translated.
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

The issue appeared after adding this line

```
.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.ToList());
```

What is the cause and how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you try any of the suggestions in the error message?

Comment: Per the message, switch to LINQ to Objects by using `.AsEnumerable()` after the `.GroupBy()`. `.ToDictionary()` is only meaningful on the client side.

Comment: EFCore 5 introduced breaking changes to the clientside evaluation model, so it needs to be done explitly.

As suggeted, put an ".AsEnumerable()" before the ".ToDictionary" to tell it to switch to client side at that point.

Comment: you could also materialize the query first by putting a `ToList( )` call after the `GroupBy` clause and then call `ToDictionary`

Comment: @JeroenMostert I've tried to use .AsEnumerable() after .GroupBy() but I got that error

Error CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' and 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions.AsEnumerable(System.Linq.IQueryable)'

could you provide me the correct syntax for doing that ?

Comment: @phuzi yes I've tried to use .ToList() and I got the same Error. and try to use  .AsEnumerable() and I got this error message 
"Error CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Linq.Enumerable.AsEnumerable<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' and 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.DynamicQueryableExtensions.AsEnumerable(System.Linq.IQueryable)'"

Comment: "yes I've tried to use .ToList()" could you please post this attempt ? I really wonder why the error still persists

Comment: Man, put ToList before GroupBy ))

Comment: @MongZhu I've tried this 

    
 `var rooms_ = context.Rooms
                            .Include(q => q.AreaType)
                            .Where(q => floorsIds.Contains(q.ParentId.Value) && q.AreaTypeId.HasValue && !q.IsDeleted)
                            .GroupBy(r => r.AreaTypeId.Value).ToList();

            var allrooms = rooms_.ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.ToList());`

 I tried to split the query to 2 queries and I got the same Error in the first one.

Comment: "Any help?" is a very broad question for a well-known issue that has already swamped the Stack Overflow ef-core tags. In other words, nothing shows that you first did a bit of research.

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to the client-side:

```
var rooms_ = context.Rooms
                    .Include(q => q.AreaType)
                    .Where(q => floorsIds.Contains(q.ParentId.Value))
                    .Where(r => r.AreaTypeId.HasValue && !r.IsDeleted)
                    .ToList()
                    .GroupBy(r => r.AreaTypeId.Value)
                    .ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.ToList());
```